# Sync DynamoDB table with a pre-defined enum key/value structure

Tags: java, database-design, enums, amazon-dynamodb, application-settings

I would like to sync the DynamoDB table with a pre-defined data structure. I am using Enum represents each item.

```
public enum Key {
    NOTIFICATION_ENABLED(false),
    ARTICLES_PER_PAGE(2),

    private final Object defaultValue;

    private Key(Object defaultValue) {
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }

    public Object getDefaultValue() {
        return this.defaultValue;
    }
}
```

By saying sync, I mean if I add a new key/value into enum or remove an existing key/value from enum, the table will sync with the structure.

These key/value is the application settings key/value pair, so they are not exposable for users to add/remove. Only admin could modify the value for the keys through the UI.

With this structure, adding a new key works fine. While removing an existing key/value from enum, I am doing this work flow:

```
Get all items in table -> Get all items in pre-defined enum -> remove the items in table but not in enum
```

Say we remove ARTICLES_PER_PAGE(2). In the first step, when getting all the items in table, DynamoDB will throw exceptions because we remove the enum key/value it is trying to map to.

How should I come over this?